# What does the '+' symbol mean at the end of a stock ticker?

Tags: stocks, ticker-symbols

For example IonQ has two tickers on the NYSE, "IONQ" and "IONQ+".

Comment: The '+' is probably not standard for NYSE tickers. The standard format would be "IONQ.WS".

Answer (score 1):

They seem to be [warrants](https://stockmarketmba.com/analyze.php?s=IONQ+) (essentially call options) that are exercisable at $11.50 per share. Since IONQ is trading at $6.23 right now it would take a pretty good rally (>100%) for them to be worth more than their cost.